# Using C# append text to each end of line of a flat file

Tags: c#, file-io

How to I append text to end of a line in a flat file using c#? Basically, I'd like to append row numbers at the end of each line.

Comment: Based on your question it sounds like answer to "How to I append text to end of a line" for your particular case is "incorrectly", but to be valid question on SO you need to show [MCVE] or at least research on how you've tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick refactor of [MasterXD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270247/masterxd)'s solution:

```
var linesInText = stringWithText.Split(Environment.NewLine);

StringBuilder stringWithRowNumbers = new StringBuilder();

var row = 1;
foreach (var line in linesInText)
{
    stringWithRowNumbers.Append(line);
    stringWithRowNumbers.Append(row++);
    stringWithRowNumbers.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
string result = stringWithRowNumbers.ToString();
```

Using StringBuilder for this is going to perform much better than simple string concatenation and is considered a best practice in this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick one line version using Linq's [Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) with index and [String.Join Method (String, String[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to rebuild the lines.

```
string path = "Path to your flat file";
var numberedText = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadAllLines(path).Select((line, index) => string.Join(" ", line.Trim(), index + 1)));
Console.WriteLine(numberedText);
```

The resulting string will have row numbers at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

By flat file i suppose you mean a normal text file?

Firstly you'd want to split a piece of text into it's lines. This is done by the following means:

```
string[] linesInText = stringWithText.Split('\n');
```

The character `\n` represents a new line. So everytime a 'new line' is present, split there. The the fucction `Split` seperates a string into parts, where the seperator is given as the input. The parts will then be made into a string array. In this case, all the lines in the text or string willbe turned into an array.

Now you'd want to add the numbers to the end of each line. This can be done in the following way:

```
string stringWithRowNumbers = "";
for (int i = 0; i < linesInText.Length; i++) // Go through all lines
{
    stringWithRowNumbers = linesInText[i] + "YourNumbers" + "\n"; // The old/first line + your numbers + new line
}
```

Now you should have a string with numbers in the end of all lines.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: I just realized you asked for row numbers. Here's the correct code.

```
string stringWithRowNumbers = "";
for (int i = 0; i < linesInText.Length; i++) // Go through all lines
{
    // The space is intentional. If there is no space, then the number will not have any space between itself and the line
    stringWithRowNumbers = linesInText[i] + " " + (i + 1) + "\n"; // The old/first line + row number + new line
}
```